# Exception when connecting to Database through Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, sqljocky

I was trying to connect to MySQL database in Flutter application using sqljocky5 using the below code using dart language

```
void getInfo () async {
    var pool = new ConnectionPool(
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3305,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'mysql',
        db: 'smartlender',
        max :5
    );
    print('test');
    var results = await pool.query('SELECT employee.firstName  FROM smartlender.employee;'); // exception is thrown here
    results.forEach((row){  // for each loop to add data to the list created above
      names.add(row[0].toString());
    });
```

Then I received this [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0INM.jpg):
I have working connection to MySQL database and the query is exiting without an error  . 
I appreciate a lot if someone could resolve this issue .

Comment: Sounds like a Dart bug. What does `dart --version` print?

Comment: Please post the full output.

Comment: i have mistakenly taken wrong value , can u tell me hot to get dart version

Comment: I missed the Flutter tag. I don't think you actually want to access MySql from a mobile device directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it default Mysql port number 3306?